# coffeescript or operator on bind "change"

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

My exsisting code looks like this...

```
jQuery ->
  to_date = null
  from_date = null
  $("#to_date").bind "change", ->
    from_date = new Date($('#from_date').val())
    to_date = new Date($('#to_date').val())
    if from_date > to_date
      $("#date_error").text("Error! Not a valid date range")
    else
      $("#date_error").text("")
  $("#from_date").bind "change", ->
    from_date = new Date($('#from_date').val())
    to_date = new Date($('#to_date').val())
    if from_date > to_date
      $("#date_error").text("Error! Not a valid date range")
    else
      $("#date_error").text("")
```

...and works great. Essentially I am looking for a change on either the from_date or to_date input boxes. I'd like to use an or operator and get rid of the duplicate code. Some like...

```
$("#to_date").bind "change" || $("#from_date").bind "change", ->
    from_date = new Date($('#from_date').val())
    to_date = new Date($('#to_date').val())
    if from_date > to_date
      $("#date_error").text("Error! Not a valid date range")
    else
      $("#date_error").text("")
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: you can use `$("#to_date, #from_date").bind "change" , ->`

Comment: Daym son. You nailed it! Put that in an answer so I can give ya some points!

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for the pointer and the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery's multiple selector to combine the selection and bind the change event on them as,

```
$("#to_date, #from_date").bind "change" , ->
```

relevant doc
[Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Regards